# What's an easier way to write text one character at a time

Tags: methods, char

I have to keep on typing the same 4 line program for each Writeline I do, is there a method i can make or an easier way?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "You wake up, you raise your head off the floor";
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            text = "You gather your senses, and you...";
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define your own method :

```
static void WriteCharByChar(string text) 
{
   foreach (char c in text)
   {
      Console.Write(c);
      Thread.Sleep(50);
   }
}
```

And then just call it :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string text = "You wake up, you raise your head off the floor";
   WriteCharByChar(text);
   Thread.Sleep(200);
   Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to continue");
   Console.ReadLine();
   text = "You gather your senses, and you...";
   WriteCharByChar(text);
}
```